# Handle HttpStatusCode inside if statement, not try/catch

Tags: c#, try-catch, http-status-codes

This code must find valid pages based on page number. This should implement logic - if page with adress `http://hostname/page/x` has OK status returned, url is valid, if response status NotFound, urls is invalid. I'd like to handle HttpStatusCode inside if statment, but it's always catch by try/catch block.

```
    public void GetAllLinks()
            {
                const string baselink = "http://buzzon.khaleejtimes.com/ad-category/real-estate/page/";
                //Check if OK status answer from server, page link is valid
                for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    var url = baselink + i;
                    if (LinkExist(url) != true)
                    {
                      try {
                        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
                        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
                        if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        {  
                            //Exit loop if status 404.  
                            break;
                        }
                        WriteUrl(url);
                        myHttpWebResponse.Close();
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex) {
                     throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                   } 
                }
                ParsePages();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll be glad if anybody offer better solution, but for now this one is working:

```
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {
                        var resp = (HttpWebResponse) ex.Response;
                        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        break;
                    }
```

I don't like this solution as it's not beatiful. So if anybody has better idea - you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public string GetAllLinks()
            {
                const string baselink = "http://buzzon.khaleejtimes.com/ad-category/real-estate/page/";
                //Check if OK status answer from server, page link is valid
                for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    var url = baselink + i;
                    if (LinkExist(url) != true)
                    {
                      try 
                      {
                        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
                        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
                      using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                      {
                        if (HttpStatusCode.OK == response.StatusCode)
                        {                           
                          WriteUrl(url);
                          myHttpWebResponse.Close();
                        }
                        else
                           break;
                     }
                  }
                  catch (Exception wex) 
                  {
                     string pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
                     return pageContent;
                   } 
                }
                ParsePages();
                return "Response Established";
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately same problem again - 404 code catch by try/catch instead of if loop.

Comment: there is no Response method in Exception. Could you check your code again please?

Comment: Check the code now, and make sure the calling function must call this function using, for example, string GetResponse = GetAllLinks();Console.WriteLine();// Display the string contents here

Answer (score 0):

```
try adding a null check ..

HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
// Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
var temp = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

if (temp == null)
{
         //break code
}
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) temp;
```

Comment: There will not null answer. There always will be some StatusCode I suppose.